# How to kill multiple laravel php artisan commands at once?

Tags: php, linux, laravel

Often when I update what's in my scheduled tasks, I need to remove what's already running. Is there a way to quickly remove them?

Currently I do this:

1. Find the task IDs with this: **ps -fe | grep artisan**
2. Kill the tasks like */usr/bin/php7.3 artisan command:my-commands-here* and "sh -c ...etc.etc. artisan etc.etc" with a kill command like: **kill 155431**

Is there a linux command I can use to kill all "artisan command:XYZ" at once?

Comment: Not sure if just killing processes is a particularly good method to use.  What are these processes doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below command. It will kill each process listed in artisan search list.

```
for pid in $(ps -fe | grep artisan); do kill $pid; done
```

Comment: This unfortunately just returns these errors:
-bash: kill: forge: arguments must be process or job IDs
-bash: kill: 06:00: arguments must be process or job IDs
-bash: kill: @: arguments must be process or job IDs
-bash: kill: 00:00:08: arguments must be process or job IDs
-bash: kill: /usr/bin/php7.3: arguments must be process or job IDs
-bash: kill: artisan: arguments must be process or job IDs
-bash: kill: command:my-commands-here: arguments must be process or job IDs
-bash: kill: new: arguments must be process or job IDs
-bash: kill: (1) - Operation not permitted

Comment: Actually, despite the errors, it does actually kill them.

Comment: @NAMAssist Please, refer this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89316/how-to-kill-a-process-that-says-operation-not-permitted-when-attempted

Comment: use sudo kill -9 $pid